# "Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on POST"

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The following code works most of the time but sometimes it throws an exception with this message:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on POST: /queries2020-09/_search?typed_keys=true

```cs
   var response = await client.SearchAsync<LogEntry>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Must(m => m.DateRange(r => r.Field(l => l.DateTimeUTC)
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(new DateMathExpression(since))),
                    m => m.Term(term)
                )))
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Sum("total-cost", descriptor => descriptor
                .Field(f => f.Cost)
                .Missing(1)))
        .Size(0));

    if (!response.IsValid)
    {                
        throw new Exception("Elasticsearch response error. " + response.ToString());
    }
```

This seems to be a very generic message that pops up a lot on Q&A websites. How do I debug it to see the root cause?

Using [NEST](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nest) 7.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to write the [debug information](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html) out rather than `.ToString()`

```
if (!response.IsValid)
{                
    throw new Exception("Elasticsearch response error. " + response.DebugInformation);
}
```

The debug information includes the audit trail and details about an error/exception, if there is one. It's a convenience method for collecting the pertinent information available on `IResponse` in a human readable form.

If a response is always checked for validity and an exception thrown, you may want to set `ThrowExceptions()` on `ConnectionSettings` to throw when an error occurs.